# How can I get another document in a design document function?

Tags: couchdb

There are some special design document functions, like `updates` and  `validate_doc_update` besides of `views` and `lists` functions; where our functions are get executed upon specific events by issuing a single document per call.

I wonder if we can fetch another document within a single `update` function, like so:

```
  updates: {

    "hello" : "function(doc, req) {
      if (doc.type === 'example') {
        otherDoc = fetch(doc.relatedDocId)
        doc.relatedDocName = otherDoc.name 
        return [doc, 'Hey Hey...']
      }
    }"
```

Point is I want to use a `fetch(documentId)` like function in order to update some other documents based on current document information.

Comment: I wanted to give you the perfect answer but I could not. Here a few options that you might think of. 

1. Client-side logic
2. Using CommonJS modules
3. Having a custom handler (your own plugin)

Comment: best option might be a custom handler (but I would loose 3rd party DBaaS functionality). second, I may implement a client-side logic. I can not imagine how CommonJS modules fit in this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

When a document is updated, there is no way in CouchDB to automatically update a second, related document. You may want to implement a worker listening to the [changes feed](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/changes.html?highlight=changes) and perform such updates there.

Comment: If this is the case, I should implement a client-side logic with `db/_bulk_docs`, since the worker process might fail which would suddenly cause the database (hence the application) to get into an inconsistent state.